# document.doctype is undefined only in IE8

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-8, doctype

Just bumped into this issue and I'm completely taken aback. Unsure how something like that would happen.

The web application is being generated using ASP.NET MVC 3. The doctype is set in the master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.UI.MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContentRoot" runat="server" /></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CssContentRoot" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log(document.doctype.name);
    </script>
</head>
```

On a given page in the application, I call this:

```
console.log(document.doctype.name);
```

In the latest Google Chrome, FireFox, and IE10/9 -- all output html.

IE8, like a champ, spits out an error indicating that doctype is undefined:

> Unable to get property 'name' of undefined or null reference

I'm not turning up anything in Google searches regarding something like this. Does anyone have any ideas which I could explore? Right now I am looking at possibly the MVC3 master page rendering incorrectly in IE8.

This happens even if I'm on an entirely blank, new project page with no master page, but does not happen in JS fiddle. Hmm

Comment: Can you try removing the whitespace before `<!DOCTYPE html>` and have it on first line with no whitespace preceding it? I recall older versions of IE encountering trouble when there was whitespace before the doctype declaration.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/mWGTfX6.png Doesn't seem to have any effect. I'm going to create a new, empty MVC3 project and see if the issue reproduces itself. EDIT: Yeah it happens even with a brand new, empty MVC3 Internet project. Going to try without a master page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_document_doctype.asp

> Note: In Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, this property returns null for HTML and XHTML documents, and will only work for XML documents.

Sorry, looks like it just isn't supported.

Comment: Hey, thanks. Interesting. My actual issue stems from the fact that I'm  using the css-content attribute and it is not working properly in IE8. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp warns about the doctype needing to be set. My example works on their page, but does not on mine, so I can only assume my doctype is not being set properly.. is there another way to ensure my doctype is set?